# Почему KVM считается гипервизором первого типа?

Tags: linux, виртуализация, kvm

Я же устанавливаю kvm на какой то дистрибутив линукса и запускаю там виртуалку, но по мимо самой виртуалки всё это время у меня же работает мой первоначальный дистрибутив со своими процессами, демонами и т.п. что соответственно отнимает ресурсы?

А на сколько я понял основное преимущество гипервизоров первого типа в том что у нас нет основной ОС и она не отнимать ресурсы?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/q/855094

Comment: Понятно. Но всё равно остается вопрос правильно ли я понимаю что сама работающая ОС отнимает какие то ресурсы? И если мне например нужна она только как гипервизор это будет не нужный оверхед, можно ли как то отключить её какую то функциональность чтобы оставить только функцию гипервизора?

Comment: Зависит от ОС и её использования. В общем случае — да. См. https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/269049 ещё.

Comment: Смысл между 1  и 2 типами не в том, что ОС нет, а в том, что первый тип работает напрямую с железом, а второй тип - через прослойку вызовов ОС

Comment: @Sheridan но если у нас есть полноценая ОС она же выполняет какие то свои служебные задачи демоны и т.п. которые занимаю процессор и память, поидеи этого нет в гипервизорах 1 ?